# How can I add months to a date in a for loop and append the result to a list or dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, date

The goal is to get a dataframe with two columns: the first column would be the month and the second column would be the year. I'd like the for loop to take me to two years from now. I left the for loop empty given that I was nowhere near finding the solution.

```
D <- data.frame(month(Sys.Date()), year(Sys.Date()))
D <- rename(D, Month = month.Sys.Date..., Year = year.Sys.Date...)

for (x in 1:24) {
     D1 <- return() 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a loop.  An option is to `paste` the 'Year', 'Month' together, convert to `yearmon` class (from `zoo`) and add a sequence of months

```
library(zoo)
 as.yearmon(paste0(D$Year, "-", D$Month)) + 0:24/12
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Error in D$Year : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
I'm using this in Azure ML, so I don't know if it has something to do with their version of R

Comment: @EAG It must be related to your `D` data.frame.  In the example, i see two columns 'Year' and 'Month'